# Values in array don't adding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When you press button (chars and digits) in document then value should be added to filterName, but only last pressed is adds. I don't understand what i do wrong.

ReactJS v.16.8.6

```js
const App = () => {
    const [filterName, setFilterName] = React.useState('')

    React.useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
        }
    }, [])
    
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(filterName)
    })

    const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
        //backspace (remove last typed symbol)
        if (event.keyCode === 8) {
            setFilterName(
                filterName
                    .split('')
                    .filter((f, index) => index !== filterName.length - 1)
                    .join('')
            )
        }
        //chars or diggits
        if (
            (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) ||
            (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) ||
            (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) ||
            event.keyCode === 32
        ) {
            setFilterName([...filterName.split(''), event.key].join(''))
        }
    }
    return <div> {filterName} </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
    }
}, [])
```

Event Listeners should add and remove like this without inputs:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress)
    }
})
```